# Running JMeter to Master & Slave machines, but at Master machine JMeter script execution not ended, so report and result not generated

Tags: jmeter, master-slave, distributed-testing

Running JMeter to Master & Slave machines, Slave is showing the script is started & finished, but at master showing "Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445", for this at master JMeter script execution not ended, so report and result not generated.
Though this script only contains a HTTP Request with a single thread, for execution it only needs few seconds. I waited for couple of hours, but not got the result.
How can i solve this problem?

for both Master & Slave machines I configured:
install jdk1.8.0_271 & jmeter5.3

on "jmeter.properties" i added : server_port=4000, client.rmi.localport=4000, server.rmi.port=4000, server.rmi.localport=4000

on "user.properties" i added :   server.rmi.port=9999, server.rmi.localport=4000

[image: Master Server]

[image: Slave Server]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Though this script only contains a HTTP Request with a single thread, for execution it only needs few seconds.` - you're running it with 100 threads and 500 seconds ramp-up so it will run for 8 minutes at least (plus time required for the last user to execute the last iteration of the sampler)
2. The fact that the slave cannot report the test finished event and the results back to the master means that the slave cannot properly communicate with the master

Assuming all above you need to open 2 ports in the slave, i.e.

- 4000 for the SERVER_PORT
- 5000 for the server.rmi.localport

and run your slave as `jmeter-server -Dserver.rmi.localport=5000 -Dserver_port=4000 -Jclient.rmi.localport=4000`

master should be executed as `jmeter -Jclient.rmi.localport=4000`

All the aforementioned ports must be opened in the firewall.

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Using a different port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#portchange)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)

Comment: Here i opened 2 ports in the slave, i.e.

* 4000 for the SERVER_PORT
* 5000 for the server.rmi.localport

also edited this ports in jmeter.properties & user properties.

But JMeter not running at Master, showing error massage that "Configuring remote engine: 192.168.0.38:5000
Using local port: 5000
no such object in table
Failed to configure 192.168.0.38:5000
Stopping remote engines
Remote engines have been stopped
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[192.168.0.38:5000]" 

https://i.imgur.com/75d0nfy.png